# .export many objects to R foreach

Tags: r, linux, foreach

I've got an R script that runs on Linux, using openmpi, doMPI, and nested foreach loops to do some big simulations on ~ 300 cores, and it works quite well.  Recently I've modulized the code into lots of individual .R files which are "sourced".  However I still have to ".export" over 70 individual objects on the inside foreach loop.  I've made several attempts to clean up the code by putting the names of all of these objects in a separate .R file, and then sourcing it.  I also thought that

```
.export=c(ls())
```

might work, just export all objects to the cores but that didn't work either.
Anyone know of a way of putting a list of object names in a file and passing the objects with those names to the cores?
Thanks
J

Comment: Please define "did not work". What is the error? What objects exactly are you collecting with `ls()`? Perhaps not all should be passed on? Can you make a small example?

Comment: I get the following error message : Error in { : task 36 failed - "object 'ProSecPos' not found", where this is a scalar variable, and the first one required in a top level function argument.  If I put ProSecPos in the list of export variables, then it will fix this error, and I will get the next error for the next argument name that has not been passed on, and so on.  There is quite likely a much simpler, more elegant way of doing this.  Thx.

Comment: Please edit your question to add pertinent information. Keep in mind that you should present the problem as if we're not over your shoulder (hint: we're not). :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use environments.

- If you want to export the variables of the Global Environment, use `.export = ls(globalenv())`.
- For the parent environment (calling function), use `ls(parent.env())`.
- For the current environment (this should not be necessary), use `ls(environment())`.